# jquery - scroll bottom a div after append an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, append

I append a new item to my list in this way as in this codepen (the same problem):
https://codepen.io/emilcarlsson/pen/ZOQZaV

HTML

```
<div id="messages">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When insert

```
$('<li id="message-' + i + '" class="msg"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" /><p>Example 1</p></li>').appendTo($('#messages ul'));
```

After insert scroll bottom div

```
$("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
```

it works well but only for the first 15/20 iterations.

see the screenshots
[image: WORKS]

[image: ISSUE]

Comment: Is there any kind of overflow-y on your messages element?  does your messages element grow in height until it gets to a max height?

Comment: can you put your codes on http://codepen.io/ to help more!?

Comment: Rather than linking to an offsite resource like codepen, edit your question and hit Ctrl+M, or the `<>` button on the editor, to bring up the onsite editor to make a live working example, or provide the source code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/emilcarlsson/pen/ZOQZaV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to scroll based on the height of your ul.  To do so there are a couple changes.

## CSS

```
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
```

The li's of the ul are breaking out of the ul, because they have a float left on them.  By giving the parent a float left and a width of 100%, the children will stay contained in it and the ul will have a height.

## Javascript

```
$(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $('.messages ul').height() }, "fast");
```

With the css change, you can now scroll based on the height of the ul, which accurately reflects the scroll distance of the element you have an overflow-y for.

Comment: i have tried to override with inline style... if modify original css works! Thanks a lot!